# Is there a tool to measure speed of your pc/laptop?

Tags: software-recommendation, performance

In Windows 7 there is a tool that calculates some kind of index of your machine: [the performance index](http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1116983.htm). I am not sure how it is done, but it is nice to know, to be able to compare machines.

Does anybody know of anything similar for ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Phoronix Test Suite is a complete benchmark facility that works on any Linux distribution, Windows and MacOSX systems.

Here are its features:

- 130+ Test Profiles 60+ Test Suites
- Extensible Testing Architecture
- Optional Linux-based LiveDVD/USB
- Testing Distribution (PTS Desktop Live) Automated Test Installation
- Dependency Management Support
- Module-based Plug-In Architecture
- PNG, JPG, GIF, Adobe SWF, SVG Graph
- Rendering Support Automated Batch
- Mode Support Global Database For Result Uploads, Benchmark Comparisons
- Detailed Software, Hardware Detection
- System Monitoring Support GTK2
- Graphical User Interface + Command-Line Interface Runs On Linux, OpenSolaris, Mac OS X, Windows 7, & BSD Operating Systems

You can download it from: http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/

Some screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

[Hardinfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardinfo) can gather information about your system's hardware and operating system, perform benchmarks, and generate printable reports either in HTML or in plain text formats.

```
sudo apt-get install hardinfo
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited my answer. Yes, checkbox-gtk wasn't the right tool.

Answer (score 4):

**Monitoring Your System Performance in Ubuntu**

You can have better system performance if you are monitoring your system properly. Every operating system has the tools and techniques to monitor the system performance , ubuntu too has tools to monitor.You can monitor your Ubuntu system in one of the following ways.

> Use System Monitor

System Monitor is a default installed utility to monitor the system. It can be loaded from Applications > System Tools > System Monitor.
[image]

> Use Saidar

You can use the saidar tool to monitor your system. It is a tool which shows system performance in terminal. So to use saidar, you must be familiar with terminal. To install it, simply run following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install saidar
```

Once installation is complete, open your terminal and type **saidar**

$saidar
[image]

You will get information about your CPU and memory in terminal.

Also see the following links,it may help you

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia_gt425_winlin&num=1

Answer (score 1):

There no application benchmark as simple as the Windows vista/7 index. Phoronix Test Suite is a really powerfull and complete benchmark tool, it would be a great addition to it, maybe we should propose it to the phoronix team.