# Are there any automated functionality tests for an Ubuntu installation?

Tags: performance, automation, testing

I have installed Ubuntu on my MIPS architecture machine (it is not an x86).

I want to test if the applications are working well. I want to use automation test methods to do it, but how can I accomplish this?

Are there any references or suggestions to do this? By the way, most of the tests are functions in the GUI, such as Gedit, Firefox, Power manager, etc

Comment: @Sepero -For Other test you can refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12055/is-there-a-tool-to-measure-speed-of-your-pc-laptop) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60961/stress-testing-hardware)

Answer (score 4):

There is a system testing tool called [`Checkbox`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Automation/Checkbox/).

"Checkbox is a test runner for Ubuntu. It aims to provide a common framework to run all types of tests, from hardware tests, to command line tests, unit tests or desktop tests and send their results to Launchpad, automatically."